# How to solve "Exception thrown: write access violation." in a C project(visual sutdio2022)

Tags: c, string, visual-studio, memory, linked-list

The  project is written and complied in the 2013 version and it works well.

I'm running the project  in visual studio 2022. The "write access violation" error occurs.

The following is the part of the project

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sJ4t.png)

```
Exception thrown: write access violation. **tail** was 0x9502760.
```

```
cellp createlink()
{
    cellp head = (cellp)malloc(sizeof(struct drink_node));
    cellp p, tail;
    int n, pr, s, a, c;
    char nam[20], ing[100];
    p = head;
    tail = head;
    tail->pre = NULL;
//error occur Exception thrown: write access violation. **tail** was 0x9502760.
    tail->next = NULL;
    FILE* fp = fopen("load_drink.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("open failed");
        return NULL;
    }

    while (fscanf(fp, "%d%s%d%d%s", &n, nam, &pr, &c, ing) != EOF)//creat a linked list
    {
        p = (cellp)malloc(sizeof(struct drink_node));
        p->num = n;
        strcpy(p->name, nam);
        p->price = pr;
        p->cost_price = c;
        strcpy(p->ingredients, ing);
        p->next = NULL;
        p->pre = NULL;
        p->pre = tail;
        tail->next = p;
        tail = p;
    }
    fclose(fp);
//    p->next = NULL;
    return head;
}

// here is the head file
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#pragma once
typedef struct drink_node {
    struct drink_node* pre;
    int    num;
    char   name[20];
    int    price;
    int    cost_price;
    char   ingredients[100];
    struct drink_node* next;
}st_drink;
typedef struct drink_node* cellp;
// cellp head, tail;
cellp createlink();
void loadUser();
void loadDrink(cellp head);


//here is the whole file

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include"Cell.h"
#include"st_User.h"
#include"cellHistory.h"
#include"warehouse.h"
usersp createlinkUsers()//会员链表
{
    usersp head = (usersp)malloc(sizeof(struct UserNode));
    usersp p=NULL,tail = NULL;
    users b;
    p = tail = head;
    tail->pre = NULL;
    tail->next = NULL;
    FILE* fp = fopen("users.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("打开文件失败!");
        return NULL;
    }
    while (!feof(fp))//创建链表拷贝数据
    {
        fread(&b, sizeof(struct st_Users), 1, fp);
        p= (usersp)malloc(sizeof(struct UserNode));
        strcpy(p->id, b.id);//复制数据
        strcpy(p->password, b.password);
        strcpy(p->name, b.name);
        p->sex = b.sex;
        strcpy(p->phone, b.phone);
        p->money = b.money;
        p->point = b.point;
        p->next = NULL;
        p->pre = NULL;
        p->pre = tail;
        tail->next = p;
        tail = p;
    }
    tail->pre->next = NULL;
    free(tail);
    fclose(fp);
    return head;
}
cellp createlink()
{
    cellp head = (cellp)malloc(sizeof(struct drink_node));
    cellp p, tail;
    int n, pr, s, a, c;
    char nam[20], ing[100];
    p = head;
    tail = head;
    tail->pre = NULL;
    tail->next = NULL;
    FILE* fp = fopen("load_drink.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("打开文件失败!");
        return NULL;
    }

    while (fscanf(fp, "%d%s%d%d%s", &n, nam, &pr, &c, ing) != EOF)//创建链表拷贝数据
    {
        p = (cellp)malloc(sizeof(struct drink_node));
        p->num = n;
        strcpy(p->name, nam);
        p->price = pr;
        p->cost_price = c;
        strcpy(p->ingredients, ing);
        p->next = NULL;
        p->pre = NULL;
        p->pre = tail;
        tail->next = p;
        tail = p;
    }
    fclose(fp);
//    p->next = NULL;
    return head;
}
historyp creatlinkHistory() {//购买记录链表
    historyp head = (historyp)malloc(sizeof(struct st_history));
    historyp p, tail;
    char id[20], n[30];
    int num = 1;
    int amount, price, cost, money = 0;//数量，价格，成本，利润
    int y = 0, m = 0, d = 0, h = 0, mi = 0;//年，月，日，小时，分钟
    int ice = 0, more = 0;//冷热，加料
    p = tail = head;
    tail->pre = NULL;
    tail->next = NULL;
    FILE* fp = fopen("purchase_history.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("打开文件失败!");
        return NULL;
    }
    while (fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d %d %d %s %d %s %d %d %d %d", &y, &m, &d, &h, &mi, id, &amount, n, &price, &cost, &more, &ice) != EOF) {
        p = (historyp)malloc(sizeof(struct st_history));
        p->num = num++;
        p->year = y;//数据拷贝
        p->month = m;
        p->day = d;
        p->minute = mi;
        p->hour = h;
        strcpy(p->id, id);
        p->amount = amount;
        strcpy(p->name, n);
        p->price = price;
        p->cost = cost;
        p->more = more;
        p->ice = ice;
        p->next = NULL;
        p->pre = NULL;
        p->pre = tail;
        tail->next = p;
        tail = p;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return head->next;
}
warep creatlinkWarehouse() {
    warep head = (warep)malloc(sizeof(struct warehouse));
    warep p, tail;
    int n, inv,price;//编号，库存，价格
    char nam[20];//名称
    p = tail = head;
    tail->pre = NULL;
    tail->next = NULL;
    FILE* fp = fopen("entrepot.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("打开文件失败!");
        return NULL;
    }
    while (fscanf(fp, "%d %s %d %d", &n, nam, &inv, &price) != EOF) {
        p = (warep)malloc(sizeof(struct warehouse));
        p->num = n;
        strcpy(p->name, nam);
        p->inventory = inv;
        p->price = price;
        p->next = NULL;
        p->pre = NULL;
        p->pre = tail;
        tail->next = p;
        tail = p;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return head->next;
}
void loadUser() {//会员信息载入文件
    FILE* fp = fopen("users.txt", "w");
    users b;
    usersp p = headUserp->next;
    while (p != NULL) {
        strcpy(b.id,p->id);
        strcpy(b.name, p->name);
        strcpy(b.password, p->password);
        b.sex = p->sex;
        strcpy(b.phone, p->phone);
        b.money = p->money;
        b.point = p->point;
        fwrite(&b, sizeof(struct st_Users), 1, fp);
        p = p->next;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
void loadDrink(cellp head) {
    FILE* fp = fopen("load_drink.txt", "w");
    cellp p = head;
    char nam[20], ing[100];
    int n, pr, c;
    while (p != NULL) {
        strcpy(nam, p->name);
        strcpy(ing, p->ingredients);
        n = p->num;
        pr = p->price;
        c = p->cost_price;
        fprintf(fp, "%d %s %d %d %s\n", n, nam, pr, c, ing);
        p = p->next;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
void loadEarning(historyp head) {
    FILE* fp = fopen("purchase_history.txt", "w");
    historyp p=head;
    char id[20], n[30];
    int num = 0;
    int amount, price, cost, money = 0;//数量，价格，成本，利润
    int y = 0, m = 0, d = 0, h = 0, mi = 0;//年，月，日，小时，分钟
    int ice = 0, more = 0;//冷热，加料
    while (p != NULL) {
        y = p->year;
        m = p->month;
        d = p->month;
        h = p->hour;
        mi = p->minute;
        strcpy(id, p->id);
        amount = p->amount;
        strcpy(n, p->name);
        price=p->price;
        cost=p->cost;
        more=p->more;
        ice=p->ice;
        fprintf(fp, "%d %d %d %d %d %s %d %s %d %d %d %d\n",y, m, d, h, mi, id, amount, n, price, cost, more, ice);
        p = p->next;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
void loadWarehouse(warep head) {
    FILE* fp = fopen("entrepot.txt", "w");
    warep p = head;
    int n, inv, price;//编号，库存，价格
    char nam[20];//名称
    while (p != NULL) {
        n = p->num;
        strcpy(nam, p->name);
        inv = p->inventory;
        price = p->price;
        fprintf(fp, "%d %s %d %d\n", n, nam, inv, price);
        p = p->next;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

I am a freshman in coding, please help me. And I will appreciate it.
Maybe I need to initialize the pointer in another way?
It seems that there is a initialize problem.
Exception thrown: write access violation. **tail** was 0x9502760.

Comment: Really need a complete program

Comment: ok, I've submitted it, thank u

Comment: thats not a complete program. we are missing all the headers

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting a green bar warning from the compiler but not an exception. I added two lines to get rid of the warning, a check for the return from malloc:

```
#include <stdlib.h>                 /* added this line */
/* ... */
    cellp head = (cellp)malloc(sizeof(struct drink_node));
    if(head == NULL)return NULL;    /* added this line */
```

Since I don't have the file I couldn't test the file reading loop, but you need the same check here. The printf is in case malloc actually fails due to the file read getting stuck in a loop.

```
    p = (cellp)malloc(sizeof(struct drink_node));
    if(p == NULL){printf("p == NULL\n"); return NULL;}       /* added this line */
```

In case there's a bug in VS2022, try:

```
    while (fscanf(fp, "%d%s%d%d%s", &n, nam, &pr, &c, ing) == 5)//creat a linked list
```